# How to resolve promises in for loop in node js

Tags: mysql, node.js, es6-promise

I have below problem

```
promises=[];
prom=new Promise((resolve,reject){
conn.query(sqls,(data,error)=>{
maindata=data;
resolve(data);
})
promises.push(prom);

prom1=new Promise((resolve,reject){

conn.query(sql,(error,data)=>{
  for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
      eachdata=data[i];
      conn.query(sql1,(error1,data1)=>{
       firstdata=data;
})

      conn.query(sql2,(error2,data2)=>{
       seconddata=data;
})

      conn.query(sql3,(error3,data3)=>{
       thirddata=data;
})

})
}
promises.push(prom1);

Promise.all(promises)
.then(function(){
res.send(json)
})
.catch((error)=>{
console.log(error)
}
```

Now how to resolve or get the data from prom1. I want all the data i.e. firstdata, seconddata and thirddata.

I am able to run all the promises but not able to figure out how to do resolve prom1. I want to resolve the prom1 after I get all the data from three database calls.

Comment: Just to clarify, inside the prom1, You call 3 queries each per element of the data that is returned by the query ?

And what are you trying to achieve here ?

Comment: Please format your code - I tried to take a crack at it and like @SupunDeSilva I got confused about what it's trying to do. I think braces & parens are missing at least, but i'm not sure exactly where...

Comment: This is sample code. I have git repository https://github.com/k-quartz/penta-consulting.git. The above problem is in routes/home.js file. I am facing the issue in prom7=Promise() (from line number 187)

Comment: if you want an easy way out, create an sp/function that generates the final outcome of prom7 and execute within a single promise without having to nest it. If that does not work for you let the crowd know. It will look cleaner as well.

Comment: I looked at the file routes/home.js, I think some of the queries can be made in to joins. Rather than attempting to run them async. If the data-set is very large you will see better performance in the async approach, other vice it is too overkill IMO and it can be refactored as well.

Comment: sent you a pull request, have a look